# Rename if file already exist in powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion

I created ps script to copy only files in the folder structure- recursive

```
cp $source.Text -Recurse -Container:$false -destination $destination.Text
$dirs = gci $destination.Text -directory -recurse | Where { (gci $_.fullName).count -eq 0 } | select -expandproperty FullName
$dirs | Foreach-Object { Remove-Item $_ }
```

it is working fine. but the problem i have files in the same names. it is not copying duplicated files. i need to rename if file already exist

source:

```
folderA--> xxx.txt,yyy.txt,
folderB-->xxx.txt,yyy.txt,zzz.txt,
folderc-->xxx.txt
```

destination (requirement)

```
xxx.txt
xxx1.txt
xxx2.txt
yyy.txt
yyy1.txt
zzz.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution where I use the [Group-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113338) cmdlet to group all items by the filename. I then iterate over each group and if the group contains more then one file, I append `_$i`to it where `$i` starts by one and gets incremented:

```
$source = $source.Text
$destination = $destination.Text


Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Count -gt 1) { # rename duplicated files
        $_.Group | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} -Process {
            $newFileName = $_.Name -replace '(.*)\.(.*)', "`$1_$i.`$2"
            $i++
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $destination $newFileName)            
        }
    }
    else # the filename is unique, just copy it.
    {
        $_.Group | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
    }
}
```

Note:
You may change the `-File` to `-Container:$false` if your PowerShell version doesn't support it. Also note that the script doesn't look into the destination folder whether a file with the same name already exist.